# how to show data in the period otherwise NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to show data  like this that  if the claim table comes in the year 2015 then it should the value basing on that date .
otherwise it should be Null

My Date increment Code :

```
Declare @t table (dt date)
declare @dt datetime, @dtEnd datetime
set @dt = '2015-01-01'
set @dtEnd = dateadd(mm, 1, @dt)
INSERT @t(dt)
select dateadd(mm, number, @dt)
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null and number < 12
    ) n
where dateadd(day, number, @dt) < @dtEnd

select dt from @t

Declare @Claim table(val varchar(10),dt date,qty int)
insert into @Claim(val,dt,qty)values
 ('plumbing','2015-01-01 00:00:00.000',32),
('Antique','2014-09-04 00:00:00.000',32),
('show','2013-10-01 00:00:00.000',32),
('valet','2015-09-01 00:00:00.000',32)
```

Required Output :

```
   dt       qty     val
2015-01-01   32   plumbing
2015-02-01  NULL
2015-03-01  NULL
2015-04-01  NULL
2015-05-01  NULL
2015-06-01  NULL
2015-07-01  NULL
2015-08-01  NULL
2015-09-01  32    valet
2015-10-01  NULL
2015-11-01  NULL
2015-12-01  NULL
```

the dates should be in 2015 then values should come otherwise Nulls if the dates in 2014 or 2013

Answer (score 0):

Please check below, I am not having sql-server as of now to validate . But this will give you the idea.

```
select CAST(dt as DATE) as dt
    , SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) = 2015 THEN qty ELSE NULL END) AS qty
    , (CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt) = 2015 THEN val ELSE NULL END) AS val
FROM Claim GROUP BY dt, val;
```

Comment: please provide an Sql-Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the year function with the case statement ..

```
select dt, qty, val, (case when year(dt)='2015' then val else null end) newval  from @claim
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select t.dt,qty,val from @t t 
left join @Claim t1 
on 
cast(t.dt as varchar(7))=cast(t1.dt as varchar(7))
```

or

```
select t.dt,qty,val from @t t 
left join @Claim t1 on 
year(t.dt)=year(t1.dt)
and 
month(t.dt)= month(t1.dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
select * from your_table where datepart(year, dt) = 2015
```

dt is your date column